function calling with agents/assistant in autogen
When performing a function call in conversable agents I get this error
python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 993, in _request
raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "None is not of type 'object' - 'messages.2.function_call'", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
assistant1 (to chat_manager):

Tell me about langchain

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
assistant2 (to chat_manager):

***** Suggested function call: retrieve_content *****
Arguments: 
{
  "message": "Information about langchain"
}
*****************************************************

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

retrieve_content is the function that connects to the vectordb
Since the message is generated it should be passed to the retrieve_content function for retrieval of relevant docs from the vectordb
